# How to manage multiple versions of a project?

Tags: git, version-control, project-management

I have a project that is open sourced using `git` for revision control. Soon, I am going to release a premium hosted version of the project as well, but there will be changes made to the code specifically for the premium hosted version (performance, etc.), that should not exist in the open source version.

I want to avoid having two separate directories/projects, because if I fix a bug in the open source version, that bug is most likely in the premium hosted version as well. I don't want to make changes in two places.

What is the best way to manage this? Simply branching in `git` won't work right, because some files need to have 2 versions: an open source version and a premium hosted version.

Comment: why was this question closed based on being opinion-based? what is an opinion when it comes to GIT?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

And yet, branching should work, and will allow you to maintain two separate versions.

If you have a bug which applies to the premium version, fix it on `master`, and merge it on `premium` branch.
Git will only merge what has changed since you branched between `master` and `premium`, ie your bug fix.
On another way to publish an hotfix both in `master` and `premium` would be to do it from the common ancestor: see "[Git merging hotfix to multiple branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10761836/6309)".

---

Update 2015: git 2.5 (July 2015) has replaced `git-new-workdir` presented below by the new command [`git worktree add <path> [<branch>]`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/68a2e6a2c80303144807c8c91a087427e3c8e727/Documentation/git-checkout.txt#L228-L233).

For more, see "[**Multiple working directories with Git?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309)".

---

Original answer 2012:

[me-and](https://stackoverflow.com/users/220155/me-and) mentions in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12153405/how-to-manage-multiple-versions-of-a-project-in-git/12153522#comment16269524_12153522) the command  **[git-new-workdir](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~blynn/gitmagic/ch07.html#_building_on_git)**.
See:

- [Working with a branch using `git-new-workdir`](http://kohei.us/2010/11/16/working-with-a-branch-using-git-new-workdir/)"
- "[The Nuclear Squid `git-new-workdir`](http://nuclearsquid.com/writings/git-new-workdir/)"

> One solution to this is to simply create another local clone of your repository. Git automatically uses hard links when you clone locally, so cloning is very fast.
>   But there is one problem with this: You now have another, separate repository you need to keep up to date.
>
> This is where `git-new-workdir` comes in.
>   Instead of doing a full-blown clone of your repository, it simply sets up a new working directory (with its own index) for you.
>   The actual repository itself is shared between the original and the new working directory. This means:
>
> - If you update one repository, the new commits are instantly visible in all other working directories as well.
> - Create a new commit or branch in one of your working directories, they’re instantly available in all working directories.
>
> Note: Even though the commits are automatically there, Git won’t update the working copy if you’ve got the same branch checked out. You’ll have to do that for yourself.

Comment: Can you give a workflow example. For example say I am working on master (open source), then need to make a change to premium. Do I simply `git checkout premium` then make my changes, then git commit. Then checkout master again?

Comment: @Justin yes, you can do that. Or you can even clone your repo twice: one in master, one in premium. That way, you can even develop in parallel. (and you can fetch changes from one local repo to another).

Comment: Yeah, what do you think is the better way, cloning the repo twice, and doing `git pulls` from each, or having one directory?

Comment: @Justin it depends on your development objectives: if you want to be able to test at any time any of those two versions, cloning is practical. But if you are mainly work on one of those version, and occasionally switch to the other, one repo is enough.

Comment: @Justin But other models exists: you can have only one local repo (with checkouts between branches), but two remotes repos for you to push to (one for pushing master, one for pushing premium): those remote repos can act as "guarded repos": see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209208/what-is-the-cleverest-use-of-source-repository-that-you-have-ever-seen/3209767#3209767 (from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330270/who-propagate-bugfixes-across-branches-corporate-development/7330826#7330826)

Comment: Rather than having multiple clones, I'd recommend taking a look at [`git-new-workdir`](http://nuclearsquid.com/writings/git-new-workdir/).

Comment: @me_and Interesting suggestion. I have included it in the answer for mroe visibility.

Answer (score 21):

The use of `worktree` is best for this purpose.

In my case, I have two version of the same software that the basics are the same but each version has some different features.

So I create two `worktree` that means, create two relevant long-running branches beside the master.

```
$git worktree add -b version-silver ..\version-silver master
$git worktree add -b version-gold ..\version-gold master
```

Then I have:

```
$git branch
master  # base stuff here
version-silver # some normal features
version-gold # some better features
```

There is one repository, but I have 3 separate folders beside each other for each branch above. And make the common changes in the master. then merge it with both other versions.

```
cd master
vim basic.cpp
git add .
git commit -m "my common edit on basic.cpp"
cd ..\version-silver
vim silver.cpp
git add .
git commit -m "my specific edit on silver.cpp"
git merge master # here I get the basic.cpp latest changes for silver project
cd ..\version-gold
git merge master # here I get the basic.cpp latest changes for the gold project
```

Specific changes of each version will go in the corresponding folder as well, and the works on each project are isolated and IDE won't be confused.

Hope that helps.